# NSControl and kind of sendActionsForControlEvents

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a problem... looking for similar method to  sendActionsForControlEvents (from iOS UIControl) for NSControl?

Is there anything similar for Mac? I need to get an info about changing state of my custom switch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just supply an IBAction for your switch, and get the state of the switch from the sender parameter.